# Edit Google Cloud Organization Name

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How can I edit the Google Cloud Organization name? I don't see how this is possible any more through the IAM Settings.

Comment: Take a look at this link: https://support.google.com/a/answer/178186?hl=en, and you should be able to edit your org name by the instructions there -:P

Comment: Did this comment/link answer your question? Consider copying it as an answer.

Answer (score 12):

On **February 14th, 2017**, Google announced a change that the Organization Name (**organization.displayName**) seen in the GCP Console would switch to the G Suite domain name.

Excerpt (example not attached):

> In the next few days the Organization picker in Cloud Console will
>   begin showing your primary domain name instead of your G Suite
>   customer name, as shown in the example attached. You will see similar
>   changes in the API and gcloud, where the display name will be rendered
>   as your G Suite’s primary domain name.

Since then, you can not change the display name of the organization in GCP as it is directly tied to the domain name in G Suite.

Comment: We renamed organization name and domain in Google Workspace, but in GCP there is still old name. How to refresh it?

Comment: @GetoX It should not take long to update. If you aren't seeing it in the console, I would try using the cloud shell and running "gcloud organizations list" which should give you the domain name, the IAM org ID and also the Google Workspace Customer ID.