# How to change organisation name on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

When trying to begin an App Engine project, I find that my organisation name is incorrect (an old domain name) and needs updating to match my current domain name.

I have struggled to find out how I can edit this and have not had any success following online instructions, could you offer some guidance please?

Thanks for suggesting the duplicate. Whilst lots of information suggests that my organisation in GCP should reflect what is defined in G-Suite, it does not and is still displayed as an old domain name.

Regards,

Josh

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Edit Google Cloud Organization Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255794/edit-google-cloud-organization-name)

Comment: Can you clarify something please: Is your G Suite Org set correctly but the org name you see in GCP is wrong? Or the org name as a whole needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to resolve itself a few days after I changed organisation name through G-Suite and also after I removed and added some projects (not sure if this is related). I am unsure why this took a little time but it was frustrating that the organisation name didn't update instantly as it makes it difficult to see whether I was doing anything wrong or not!