# Update Display Name of Organization Resource in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

In GCP there is the concept of an "organization resource". As far as I understand, this is created automatically when a GSuite customer of an organization uses GCP for the first time. I also understand, that the display name of the GCP organization resource is identical to the primary URL of the GSuite organization, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43255794/edit-google-cloud-organization-name).

Now, I just recently changed the primary URL of my organization. I expected this to also be reflected in the name of the GCP organization resource. I waited 48h, no change. GSuite support told me that these are decoupled entities and changes in GSuite will not percolate to GCP and I have to change it on my own.

Now, it seems like that in the GCP UI (screenshot) there generally is the option to change the organization resource display name. However, this requires the resourcemanager.organization.update permission which, as per [here](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/organizations/update) is deprecated.

**Question: Am I missing something, or is changing the organization resource display name simply not possible anymore?**

[image]

Comment: For some operations, like migrate a project from an organization to another one, it's not possible by the GUI. However, contact the support or your Custom Engineer and ask them. Most of time, there is a solution for you. You aren't the first one who change company name because of rebranding or merging. Then, post the process here, it can help others !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so it seems that **waiting a bit more than 48h did the trick**. The GCP organization resource name indeed is **changed automatically** to the GSuite organization primary URL. But it takes some time.

Answer (score -1):

As per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1beta1/organizations#update-deprecated) the name for the organization can't be changed since the update it's deprecated, the only way possible to do it, is to create a new domain and a new organization with the new domain.

Comment: Thanks. The suggestion action is definitely one way (brute force) to go, but I doubt it's the only way to go.